# Spring - How to validate min/max value of elements in byte[] in DTO/POJO?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I was trying to find it but I can't. 
I have my DTO where I am validating the data sent by user.

```
    import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

    @Min(value = 0)
    @Max( value = 6)
    private byte[] days;
```

It is throwing an error:

> No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Min' validating type 'short[]'. Check configuration for 'days'.

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing to do with the JPA API. This is the Bean Validation API, and maybe you need a Bean Validation API implementation in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong contraints, Min and Max validates actual value, but you have an array. For validation of array length, use

```
@Size(min=0, max=6)
private byte[] days;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html

If you want to check if EVERY element of array has value between 0 - 6, you probably have to create your own validator

Comment: Yes, I want to validate value of each element. Wouldn't work the Max.list?

Comment: I don't think so.. Are you using hibernate validator?